# Using downloaded fonts without internet connection

Tags: css, fonts

It's possible to use downloaded fonts on a local web page (XAMPP) without internet connection ? I need this to see the fonts because some people maybe can't afford internet connections and they use theirs computers only to work.

This is the web font: http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/didact-gothic

I tried this with no luck: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Thanks in advance!!!!

**EDIT**

I think the place where the files are stored is the problem because I have this .css and no work. The place of all my files is `/opt/lammp/htdocs`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DidactGothicMedium';
    src: url('didactgothic.eot');
    src: url('didactgothic.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('didactgothic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('didactgothic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('didactgothic.svg#DidactGothicMedium') format('svg');
}

p {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
} 

input {
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: You have to use a web font kit, which you can download from sites like  convertfonts.com, include the style and font files and the font will work on local development, but for that you first need a otf or ttf file for the font to download the webkit

Comment: Thanks so much boom_Shiva!! The problem now is where I must to put all files because I'm trying to load them and no result. Thanks!!

Comment: How do you plan on getting visited by people that don't have an internet conenction???

Comment: Downloading all the code and later installing it on local

Comment: Then just add the font to the download?

Comment: How does XAMPP relate to the issue? Do you expect your visitors to run XAMPP?

Comment: Please describe the scenario in the question, not just in comments. How do you expect people to use your pages? How would they download them? Fonts *can* be used via `@font-face` purely locally, but from your description, it is impossible to infer what goes wrong. Consider uploading the site on web server and posting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, if you just go to your localhost in the browser it should work just like when you would port forward it and go there with your own IP/Domain.

If that @font isn't working for you, make sure 1) You use Chrome/Firefox (Internet explorer only supports certain file exentions (.otf I think).

and 2) You have the right path setup!

Also maybe some of your html/css code could help us awnser your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a web font kit, which you can download from sites like http://convertfonts.com, include the style and font files and the font will work on local development, but for that you first need a otf or ttf file for the font to download the webkit.

just make a fonts folder, like you have css, js folder and in your css file just include /fonts/, like

```
  @font-face { font-family: 'MuseoSans-100'; 
  src: url('fonts/museosans-100.eot'); 
  src: url('fonts/museosans-100.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('fonts/museosans-100.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('fonts/museosans-100.ttf') format('truetype'), 
       url('fonts/museosans-100.otf') format('opentype'), 
       url('fonts/museosans-100.svg#MuseoSans-100') format('svg'); 
  } just an example
```

if your css file is in another folder make the changes to url, correspondingly